# universal links not working swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have implemented universal links in my app with following steps :-

- turn on app domains in certificate and create provisioning file
- install certificate and provisioning profile
- turn on associated domain in capabilities
- enter the link on which I have to perform universal links with format (applinks:www.xxxxxxx.com)
- cross verifies on .entitlements file
- In identity and type of entitlement file, target membership box has been selected
- txt file has been uploaded on server with format :-

  {"applinks": {"apps": [], "details": [{"appID": “teamId.com.abcd.efgh”, "paths": ["*"]}]}}
- checked the site with validation which shows

  a) apple validator
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPIjo.png)

  b) aasa-validator
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2stoZ.png)
  ￼
- Implemented the function in my appDelegate but it is never called

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {}

My universal link is not working I am not able to redirect my app from links in notes or from any place. I
 have implemented all the neccessary steps I know. I am not able to debug the issue.

Comment: HI Manishis your problem solved,If yes please go through this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49767069/struck-in-universal-link-app-is-not-showing-in-the-safari and answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

Your AppDelegate implementation is not complete yet, you need to get your url from the received NSUserActivity object as declared [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) in apple documentations, use following method to complete your appDelegate implementation:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
            let url = userActivity.webpageURL

            else
        {return false}

        return true
}
```

Then, you can use this `url` and send it to whatever ViewController want to load it in.
Hope this helps;)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it as txt file but it should be a file with no extension and the name of the file should be "**apple-app-site-association**" and it must be present in root directory or .well-known directory in your server.

Check this article:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains