# Universal Links not working and banner is not showing in Safari

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I am working on Universal Links in my app.

When the url hits the safari it should show the option to open the app in a banner at the top of the Safari browser, but I don't see it.

I created apple-app-site-association and hosted it on my backend. When I check it https://www.xxxxx.com/apple-app-site-association . I can see the app-site-association file.

In the Entitlements I've added associated domains under items applinks:v100.xxxxxx.com/reset_password*. The link is https://v100.xxxxxxx.com/reset_password?token=6d3ec67ff5bbf2214c895839c125e8f80ec83a90  and the  apple-app-site-association is like this

```
{
 "applinks": {
 "apps": [],
 "details": [
 {
  "appID": "Teamid.Bundelid",
  "paths": ["*"]
 }
{
"appID": "appid.Bundelid",
"paths": ["*"]
}
]
}
}
```

Thanks for quick response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This banner should show up if Universal Links are configured properly. It seems like your Universal Linking is not configured.

### Your entitlement's associated domains has a LINK, not a DOMAIN

At first glance, it looks like your entitlements file has the full URL when it really should just have the domain. Change your entitlements to have `applinks:v100.xxxxxx.com` instead of `applinks:v100.xxxxxx.com/reset_password*`. If that doesn't do the trick, then keep reading

### Still broken? Try these steps

It looks like your AASA file is hosted correctly, so I recommend trying these steps:

1) Make sure that your entitlements file is included in your project. This is necessary for downloading the AASA. Ensure that your domains are correct.

[image: App Entitlements]

2) Check if your phone is running iOS 11.2. This version of iOS is having trouble actually downloading the AASA file sometimes. To solve this you should delete the app, restart your phone, then reinstall it. I recommend checking the device logs to see whether it is being installed properly. (I'd recommend doing this when you update your AASA just for sanity)

3) Check to see whether you have disabled Universal Links in your app (probably not your issue but check). You can do this by copying the link into the Notes app then long pressing on it to prompt an action sheet. If you see "Open in App name" then you can select that to turn on your Universal Links for that app. If you don't see that then the AASA file was not downloaded or configured properly.

4) Use [Branch's iOS SDK](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/ios/) for deep linking. It will save you SO MANY HOURS of debugging. They handle the AASA file for you as well as providing the deferred deep linking solution and other edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

To prompt browser user with a banner for iOS app you have to add this line to the HTML, there are no Universal Links included in this.

```html
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

When implementing Universal Links you are taking care of that users doesn't even reach the Safari browser, but to be taken directly to your app. Configuration for the Universal Links seems fine. Make sure you remove your app from the device and install it again every time you make changes to any Universal Link configuration. If you want to read more about it I recommend these links

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/universal-links-in-ios-79c4ee038272

Comment: thanks for quick response when check AASA in this link https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox it is giving below error   v100.xoxoday.com – This domain has some validation issues
A request to this domain failed.
 HTTPS error check did not run. We’ll check that your file is served over HTTPS. Make sure your network provider supports SSL/TLS. Branch can make this easier for you. 
 Server error check did not run. 
 Content type test did not run. Be sure to define a ‘content-type’ header.
 JSON test did not run. Your file should contain valid JSON.

Comment: I add it and reuploded in the back end,still problem didnot solve,Is ap shold be in appstore for doing universal linking

Comment: How are you testing this? You can't test by entering URL in Safari, you have to tap on the link somewhere, you can just type it in the notes and tap it there.

Comment: yes I am coping the link and pasted in the safari and tried but i don't work and tried by typing the link in safari but i din't work,I am testing in the simulator

Comment: Type the link in the notes and hit return so it turns into a link and then tap on it. You don't need Safari in any step to test Universal Links

Comment: simulator will not have notes so i just add the link in the message and clicked on the link i navigated to the safari the app is not showing.